# R - pheatmap - annotations doesnt show

Tags: r, pheatmap

I want to annotate my `pheatmap`, but the annotations doesn't show and I am not getting any error message.

I used the code below:

```
anno = t(data.frame(df[,c("disease")]))
ph = pheatmap(df, annotation = anno)
ph
```

Really appreciate help with this!

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset using `dput(df)`

Comment: Thanks for answeringI work in TSD so cannot export, but I have the; dim(df) 174 97, str(df) - all numeric. Dim(anno) 174 1, str(anno) chr. Can i prove other info that is helpful? If I do pheatmap(df) it shows the same as with the code aboce - the heatmap without annotations. –

Comment: Use `head(dput(df))`and then copy and paste the data in your question. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example